# Distance of two closed sets equal to the distance of their boundaries

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let $(\mathbb R^n,d)$ be the standard metric space with the euclidean distance $d$.
Let $ A, B \subseteq \mathbb R^n$, **closed** and **disjoint** subsets, and let $\partial A$ be the boundary of the set $A$.
Let $d(A,B)=inf_{a\in A, b\in B} \{d(a,b)\} $. I want to prove that $d(A,B)=d(\partial A, \partial B).$
Is my proof right? Otherwise, do you have a proof for this problem?

First of all, I want to show that $d(A,B)\le d(\partial A, \partial B)$.
$A, B$ are closed, so $\partial A \subseteq A$ and $\partial B \subseteq B$. Thus, $inf_{a\in A, b\in B} \{d(a,b)\}=d(A, B)\le d(\partial A, \partial B)=inf_{a\in \partial A, b\in \partial B} \{d(a,b)\} $ using the properties of infimum of sets and subsets.

Then, I need to show that $d(\partial A, \partial B)\le d(A,B)$. $\forall a\in A, b\in B, a_{f}\in \partial A, b_{f}\in \partial B$, using triangle inequality and definition of distance, we have $$ d(a_{f},b_{f})\le d(a_{f},a)+d(a,b)+d(b,b_{f})$$ So we can "take the infimum" and, since $inf_{a\in A, a_{f}\in \partial A} \{d(a,a_{f}) \}=0=inf_{b\in B, b_{f}\in \partial B} \{d(b, b_{f}) \}$, we have $$inf_{a\in \partial A, b\in \partial B} \{d(a_{f},b_{f})\}=d(\partial A, \partial B)\le d(A, B)=inf_{a\in A, b\in B} \{d(a,b)\}  $$

Are there any mistakes?

Comment: I'm not considering the case of A compact, only closed.

Comment: Am I allowed to "take the infimums" the way I did?

Comment: I think you "proof" would work for arbitrary subsets $A' \subset A$ and $B' \subset B$ instead of $\partial A$ and $\partial B$. Since the statement is not correct in that generality, your argument is not sufficient.

Comment: How can I improve it? Do you have any suggestions? (or do you know where to find a proof of it?)

Comment: $d(A,B)=inf_{a\in A, b\in B} \{d(a,b)\}$ is wrong.

Comment: why? I took it as a natural defintion. which definition is correct?

Comment: @WilliamElliot - There are many ways to define the distance bwtween sets. When the terminology is used without out any qualifiers, the definition here is [the one most commonly meant](https://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~cs4te3/examples/dist_sets.pdf). Maybe you are thinking of [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance)? Or some other variant?

Comment: Where did you use the fact that the sets are disjoint? If you didn't, then there is something wrong, because it is a necessary property.

Comment: @AdrianoBanchieri.  It's the notation that is wrong.

Comment: Your proof does not work because the infimum of a sum is in general not the sum of infima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following suggestion. It suffices to prove the following.

**Claim.** Let $0<\varepsilon<d(A,B)$ and $a\in A$, $b\in B$ such that $d(a,b)< d(A,B) + \varepsilon$. Then $d(a,\partial A), d(b,\partial B) < \varepsilon$.

Note that, once the Claim is proved, by fixing $a'\in \partial A$ and $b'\in \partial B$ such that $d(a,a')< d(a, \partial A) + \varepsilon$ and $d(b,b')< d(b, \partial B) + \varepsilon$, we will have that
\begin{align*}
d(\partial A,\partial B) & \leq d(a',b') \\ & \leq d(a',a) + d(a,b) + d(b,b') \\
& < d(a,\partial A) + d(a,b) + d(b,\partial B) + 2\varepsilon \\ &< d(A,B) + 5\varepsilon, 
\end{align*}
and by the arbitrariness of $\varepsilon>0$, it will follow that $d(\partial A,\partial B)\leq d(A,B)$.

So let us prove that $d(a,\partial A)<\varepsilon$, then $d(b,\partial B)<\varepsilon$ will follow by analogy.

Consider the ball $B(a,\varepsilon)$. We just need to see that $B(a,\varepsilon)\cap\partial A\neq \emptyset$. Suppose by contradiction that $B(a,\varepsilon)\cap\partial A = \emptyset$. Since $A$ is the disjoint union of its interior ${\rm int}(A)$ with its boundary $\partial A$, we must have $$B(a,\varepsilon)\subset {\rm int}(A)\subset A.$$

Now, consider the line segment $S=\{(1-\alpha)a + \alpha b: \alpha\in[0,1]\}$ joining $a$ and $b$. We will show that there exists $p\in S\cap A$ such that $d(p,b)<d(A,B)$, which will be a contradiction with the minimality of $d(A,B)$, and the proof will be finished.

Since $d(a,b)< d(A,B) + \varepsilon$, we may fix $\beta$ such that
$$
\frac{d(a,b)-d(A,B)}{d(a,b)}<\beta<\frac{\varepsilon}{d(a,b)},
$$
and it's not so hard to see that $\beta\in(0,1)$. Put $p=(1-\beta)a + \beta b\in S$ and notice that
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}d(a,p) = \|a-p\|=\beta d(a,b)<\varepsilon \\ d(b,p) = \|b-p\|=(1-\beta)d(a,b)< d(A,B)\end{array}\right..
$$
Then, since $B(a,\varepsilon) \subset A$, we have $p\in S\cap A$ satisfying $d(p,b)<d(A,B)$, and we are done.

Comment: Perhaps you should explicitly point out that $A \cap B = \emptyset$ is needed to conclude $d(a,b) > 0$.

Comment: Indeed! Actually, we could have $A$, $B$ closed, disjoint and still $d(A,B)=0$. Just consider the $x$-axis and the graph of the function $x\mapsto 1/x$, $x>0$.